# Query with multiple WHERE and CASE PHP(CodeIgniter) MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'd like to select **all period** of current term (as now FY80) + **3 period only** of last term (FY79) from **m_period** table

Here's the table **m_period** looks :

```
+----+------+-------------+--------+
| id | term | period      | status |
+----+------+-------------+--------+
|  1 | FY79 | 79::2020/01 | close  |
|  2 | FY79 | 79::2020/02 | close  |
|  3 | FY79 | 79::2020/03 | close  |
|  4 | FY79 | 79::2020/04 | close  |
|  5 | FY79 | 79::2020/05 | close  |
|  6 | FY79 | 79::2020/06 | close  |
|  7 | FY80 | 80::2020/07 | open   |
|  8 | FY80 | 80::2020/08 | open   |
|  9 | FY80 | 80::2020/09 | open   |
| 10 | FY80 | 80::2020/10 | open   |
| 11 | FY80 | 80::2020/11 | open   |
| 12 | FY80 | 80::2020/12 | open   |
| 13 | FY80 | 80::2021/01 | open   |
| 14 | FY80 | 80::2021/02 | open   |
| 15 | FY80 | 80::2021/03 | open   |
| 16 | FY80 | 80::2021/04 | open   |
| 17 | FY80 | 80::2021/05 | open   |
| 18 | FY80 | 80::2021/06 | open   |
+----+------+-------------+--------+
```

my php script stuck from here :

```
<?php

function getPeriod()
{
    $prev_term = (int)substr($this->session->userdata('term'),2,2) - 1;
    $this->db->select('period');
    $this->db->where('term', $this->session->userdata('term'));
    $this->db->where('term', $prev_term);
    $this->db->order_by('period', 'ASC');
    return $this->db->get('m_period')->result_array();
}
```

I've read CI documentation and couldn't find how to use CASE in codeigniter, or there is another way instead of using CASE ?
can someone help me , how to do this ?

**Note : I store current term on session**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [limit()](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#id5) method.

Then, You have to have two separate functions.

```
function getPrevPeriod()
{
    $prev_term = (int)substr($this->session->userdata('term'),2,2) - 1;
    $this->db->select('period');
    $this->db->where('term', $prev_term);
    $this->db->order_by('period', 'ASC');
    $this->db->limit(3);
    return $this->db->get('m_period')->result_array();
}

function getCurrentPeriod()
{
    $this->db->select('period');
    $this->db->where('term', $this->session->userdata('term'));
    $this->db->order_by('period', 'ASC');
    return $this->db->get('m_period')->result_array();
}
```

Then you can use `array_merge()` to combine arrays.

```
$periods = array_merge($prev, $current);
```

**Edit:**  With one query

```
function getPeriod()
{
    $prev_term = (int)substr($this->session->userdata('term'),2,2) - 1;
    $this->db->select('term','period');
    $this->db->or_where_in('term',[$this->session->userdata('term'),$prev_term])
    $this->db->order_by('period', 'ASC');
    $result = $this->db->get('m_period')->result_array();
    $output = [];
    $n = 0;
    foreach($result as $row){
         if($row["term"] == $prev_term){
              if($n <= 3){
                   $output[] = $row;
                   $n++;
              }
         }else{
              $output[] = $row;
         }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: thanks , this might work, 
but i wonder if it could be done in one function and one query
next question is how to join these two result into a single output data, i will use the output for dropdown html list btw

Comment: i tried with your one query method but the result goes nothing, then i modified it a bit by using or_where_in() instead of where, then it works, thanks man  :)

Comment: Could you please edit my answer ? Then, People with same issues may find this helpful.